# French characters on highchart r

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm trying to make a map of France to illustrate some frequencies, but there is an error when using the data labels since french characters are not recognized.

[image: French departments]

For instance La Réunion is displayed as la RA@union.

Is there a way to use a different data set for the data labels?
 This is my code:

```
mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/fr/fr-all-all"))  
data_fake <- mapdata %>% 
  select(code = `hc-a2`) %>% 
  mutate(frequence = 0.5 * abs(rt(nrow(.), df = 10)))

glimpse(data_fake)
## Observations: 52


hcmap("countries/fr/fr-all-all", data = data_fake, value = "frequence",
      joinBy = c("hc-a2", "code"), name = "Fake data",
      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}'),
      borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
      tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2, valuePrefix = "$", valueSuffix = " USD")) %>% 
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in the development version of `highcharter`.

source: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/commit/722f69a5ba8856eaa74623a8fef4bc6fcb542694

Comment: Thank you, although I'm unable to install the dev version, but that is a different problem